# What are or where can I find style guidelines for writing math?

Tags: reference-request, education, article-writing, publishing

I am a scientist writing my first manuscript with a substantial amount of mathematical methodological documentation.

I am using LaTeX, but this is not my question.

I would like to find a list of usage rules similar to [Strunk and White](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style). I can follow the practices that I see in my field, but it would be helpful to know the underlying rules and recommendations that will help me explain mathematical concepts in a reproducible and understandable way.

**Update** In addition to excellent answers and resources below, this recent (2018) paper directly and comprehensively answers my question:

[Edwards, Andrew M., and Marie Auger‐Méthé. "Some guidance on using mathematical notation in ecology." Methods in Ecology and Evolution.](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/2041-210X.13105)

Comment: http://books.google.com/books?id=9gQd2fJA7Y4C

Comment: This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but [Tao](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/advice-on-writing-papers/) has good advice and includes on his page any other source I would consider referencing.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/book-about-technical-and-academical-writting/7032#7032) previous post.

Comment: And if you have time, you should watch J.P. Serre's lecture ["How to Write Mathematics Badly"](http://wstein.org/edu/basic/serre/) for what *not* to do.

Comment: I like how that book I mentioned was so good, it showed up in the answers as well... :D

Comment: See also: [Book about technical and academic writing](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/7011).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's what is in my shelf, in the order in which I picked them up:

- *Mathematics into Type* (Updated Edition). American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1999, ISBN 0-8218-1961-5. It includes what the usual submission/refereeing process is, how to mark manuscripts, how to space symbols, in-line equations, and display equations (and how to break long equations across lines). It does not discuss matters of *style* (how a mathematician usually *says* certain things), however. [Available online.](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/mit-2.pdf)
- *Handbook of Writing for the Mathematical Sciences* by Nicholas J. Higham. Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics, Philadelphia PA, 1993. ISBN 0-89871-314-5. It includes a section on Mathematical Writing (Chapter 3) and one on English Usage (Chapter 4), as well as tips on organizing a paper and the like. I'll add that Chapter 2 ("Writer's Tools and Recommended Reading") contains a wealth of references.
- *A Primer of Mathematical Writing. Being a disquisition on having your ideas recorded, typeset, published, read, and appreciated* by Steven G. Krantz. American Mathematical Society, Providence RI, 1997, ISBN 0-8218-0635-1. One full chapter devoted specifically to mathematical writing ("How to State a Theorem", "How to Prove a Theorem", "How to State a Definition", etc).
- Paul R. Halmos. *How to write mathematics*. Enseign. Math. **16** (1970), pp. 123-152. A very good read, cited by every other work mentioned above. Also available on the web, as a quick google search will reveal; e.g., [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Eazoff/courses/halmos.pdf).
- *How to write mathematics*, corrected edition, by Norman E. Steenrod, Paul R. Halmos, Menahem M. Schiffer, and Jean A. Dieudonné. American Mathematical Society, Providence RI 1981, ISBN 0-8218-0055-8. A reprint of four papers on writing mathematics, including Halmos's paper mentioned above.
- *Writing Mathematics Well: A Manual for Authors* by Leonard Gillman. Mathematical Association of America, 1987, ISBN 0-88385-443-0 (page ix reads: "This manuscript was prepared by the author on an Apple Macintosh with the help of Mac$\Sigma$qn, a program for symbols and equations"; how times have changed...)
- *Mathematical Writing*, by Donald E. Knuth, Tracy Larrabee, and Paul M. Roberts. MAA Notes no. 14, The Mathematical Association of America, 1989, ISBN 0-88385-063-X; this is a bit of an odd duck, in my opinion. They are the class notes for a course on mathematical writing taught by Knuth.

There are other, more general guides; I keep a copy of Fowler's "Modern English Usage" and the "Oxford Guide to English Usage" always available, as well as a copy of the Chicago Manual of Style (14th edition) and of Strunk and White at home (recently joined by *Eats, Shoots and Leaves: the zero tolerance approach to punctuation* by Lynne Truss; now I can tell my students that the semi-colon was invented by the same guy who invented italics). Mary-Claire van Leunen's *A Handbook for Scholars* (revised edition) is a classic as well. But these are not specific to mathematics, and a lot of the advice has to be actively disobeyed to follow standard mathematical phraseology or uses (many a copywriter unaccustomed to mathematics has choked on "a Green's function").

*Added:* I don't think you will necessarily pick up the traditional jargon/cadence of mathematics from any of the above sources, however. That's something that is picked up by osmosis, through hearing and reading a lot of mathematics. But this even happens across fields, not just across disciplines; one can often spot that someone is new to a particular field within mathematics by how he or she phrases certain statements, which is at odds with the usual practices of the sub-field in question. But the advice you get in any of the above (my recommendations, in no particular order, are Higham, Krantz, and Halmos for writing content, and *Mathematics into Type* for final preparation of the manuscript for submission, especially if you are submitting to a mathematics journal) should carry you through.

Comment: Shouldn't "Green's" have an apostrophe somewhere? ;)

Comment: "That's something that is picked up by osmosis, through hearing and reading a lot of mathematics." - agreed. You learn to write like "them" by reading "them".

Comment: @J.M. Oops. Quite so. In fact, it's "a Green's function" that is in the anecdote related by Krantz, of a copy-writer to told him it must be changed to "the function of Mr Green".

Comment: I understand where the copywriter's coming from, but I'm still snickering...

Comment: Worth adding that since this answer, *Mathematics into type* (excellent in its time) has evolved into more up-to-date *The AMS Style Guide*, available [here](https://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

An excellent reference is

- Krantz, Steven. A primer of mathematical writing. AMS (1997).

It covers much more than just papers, and I recommend it even to people with some experience. (There is a more technical book by Krantz in the same vein that treats books more extensively, "Mathematical publishing, a guidebook".)

Another excellent source, particularly because of Halmos's essay, is the short pamphlet

- Steenrod, Norman; Halmos, Paul; Schiffer, Menahem; Dieudonné, Jean. How to write mathematics. AMS (1973).

Finally, some colleagues have recommended the following as well:

- Higham, Nicholas. Handbook of writing for the mathematical sciences. SIAM (1993).

Hope this helps!