# Are there journals related to mathematical writing - by this I mean styles of writing, organization, formatting etc...

Tags: soft-question, article-writing

Are there journals where one can submit ideas on mathematical writing style eg: how to improve style, clarity, formatting etc. The closest I can find is journals related to mathematical education, but I'm not sure this would be a good fit.

Comment: There are _books_ on this topic. See the answers to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14189/what-are-or-where-can-i-find-style-guidelines-for-writing-math. Perhaps the pace of innovation in mathematical writing is so much slower than in mathematics itself (with good reason) that the book-publishing cycle is fast enough to keep up with it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Typically, if you have your own mathematical style and want to share it with the world, you start by employing it in a peer reviewed paper that you publish in a scientific journal. Preface the text with an explanation of the new style that you are using. If others read your paper and like your style, they may use it in their papers as well. If enough people use it, it may be used as a standard--the style may even be named after you.