# Mathematical Research Formatting

Tags: reference-request, publishing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are or where can I find style guidelines for writing math?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14189/what-are-or-where-can-i-find-style-guidelines-for-writing-math)

In mathematical research papers, in what tense is it most appropriate to write?  From my understanding, the present tense first person is typical (with we).  Is this correct?  Furthermore, what resources are available which describe how to write and format such papers correctly and succinctly? Note: I am not talking about math homework for university courses or anything similar to that, but rather specifically formal research papers.

Comment: Here's another... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/book-about-technical-and-academic-writing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Halmos, Paul. **[How To Write Mathematics](http://www.mat.uc.pt/~pedro/lectivos/LaTeX/how-to-write-mathematics.pdf)**
2. Cameron, Peter. **[How To Write Mathematics](http://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/how-to-write-mathematics/)**