# Which do you recommend for learning how to write proofs — How to Prove it by Velleman, or How to Solve it by Polya?

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing, book-recommendation

Which of these two books is suited for a student looking to learn how to write proofs?
I have a working knowledge of calculus and linear algebra, but I'm not good at writing proofs. My intention is to learn proofs in general, not necessarily for the calculus and linear algebra.

- [*How to Prove it*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521675995) by Daniel Velleman
- [*How to Solve It*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/4871878309) by George Polya

I ask because the latter is suggested on a highly voted question here, but the former has a more apt name. The reviews aren't helping. You can suggest other books.

Comment: Perhaps this will be an unpopular answer, but I found the best way to learn how to write proofs was to read them and imitate them.

Comment: See also [Book about technical and academic writing](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/book-about-technical-and-academic-writing) and posts which are shown there among linked questions.

Comment: @Holdsworth88: I always tell that to my students, and they always look at me like "Nobody ain't got time for that!"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Velleman's *How to Prove it* is quite a bit more relevant to your needs.  It is organized like a conventional text, and pays a lot of attention to proof *writing*.

Polya's book focuses on problem-solving. One can view it as a better book, certainly a historically far more important book. But it focuses on how one finds the *idea* that will crack a concrete problem.

There is quite a bit of material in *Velleman* that is useful for writing proofs in linear algebra, in particular on how to proceed from definitions. There is none of that in *Polya*.  There is also essentially nothing in *Polya* on basic analysis. *Polya* beautifully accomplishes his aims: they just happen to be different from what you said you wanted.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7743/getting-better-at-proofs suggests otherwise hence the doubt.

Comment: There will inevitably be differences of opinion. But I am quite convinced that *Velleman* will be far more useful to you in writing proofs associated with your *courses*. If you were a young person getting into contest-type mathematics, my advice would be different.

Answer (score 10):

The Polya is more advanced than I think you are looking for.  It is a well-known classic, but assumes the reader already knows how to write proofs.

I haven't seen it, but the Velleman should be good for you.  Another one I have seen is by Solow:
[How to Read and Do Proofs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470392169)

Comment: Can you elaborate on more advanced? I am a programmer and can work with matrices, scipy, numpy and all. Enough?

Comment: Edited.  It assumes the reader already knows how to write proofs.

Comment: Assumes reader knows to write proofs? To what extent?

Answer (score 5):

I know it's not one of the two you referred to, but you might want to look at *How to Think Like A Mathematician* by Kevin Houston.

Answer (score 4):

Another book that you should check out is Gary Chartrand's *Mathematical Proofs: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics*. It has an instructor solutions manual.