# Learning to write the style of mathematics texts

Tags: education, article-writing

When learning how to write articles in mathematics (in style of articles published in journals) is there a good reference listing things like common outlines, style guides, phrases, common mistakes etc.

Both books and websites are welcome. Let me know if I need to clarify myself.

(I know about LaTeX and a fair bit of mathematics, this question is more about how to formulate oneself when writing. Each scientific field has its own expressions and styles.) Thank you!

Comment: Some people like Paul Halmos's "How to write mathematics." Terry Tao has also written quite a bit about how to write a math paper.

Comment: Don Knuth in 1987: http://jmlr.org/reviewing-papers/knuth_mathematical_writing.pdf

Comment: Read papers/books in the area, emulate what you like (and avoid what you don't).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/book-about-technical-and-academic-writing and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14189/what-are-or-where-can-i-find-style-guidelines-for-writing-math